# how to execute method or DML in foreach loop as parallel to accelarate execution time?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework, linq

I have the following code which do query table and update rows inside it, 
then execute insert depending on previus query:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            doDBDML();
        }

private void doDBDML()
        {
            using (ThreadingDBEntities db = new ThreadingDBEntities())
            {
                var rows = db.people.Where(x => x.id == null).ToList();

                foreach (person p in rows) // how to execute it in parallel.
                {
                    p.id = p.personID; // update null value.

                    // execute stored procedure which has output parameter to get id (return existing id or insert new row and get its id).
                    ObjectParameter outParam = new ObjectParameter("p_id", typeof(Int32));
                    db.sp_getCompanyId(p.company, outParam);

                    // and new row. this depends on current person object id , and company id which has returned from stored precedure.
                    User_Company userComp = new User_Company();
                    userComp.person_Id = p.personID;
                    userComp.Company_Id = (Int32) outParam.Value;

                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
```

The store procedure is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getCompanyId]
    @p_ocmpany_Name nvarchar(255),
    @p_id int output
AS
    SELECT @p_id = id
    from Company
    where Company_name = @p_ocmpany_Name

    if @p_id is null 
    begin
        begin transaction;
        insert into Company (company_name) values (@p_ocmpany_Name);
        select @p_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
        commit transaction; 
    end;
RETURN @p_id
```

this works fine, but the problem is:
- The query returns a huge number of rows, so the execution takes a long time to execute, how to accelerate it? how to call the above doDBDML method to execute it as parallel or bulk execution?

- while executing the application on huge number of rows, it doesn't response, how to solve this issue? running it in background or as new thread ???

My question is related to windows forms application, however I also want to know if the solution is good for asp.net

Comment: I think some code refactoring is in order here. Where is your list of person & company coming from? The question should not be about running multiple inserts in parallel, it should be about how to make it a set-based operation so you only make one stored proc call and the back end does all the rest. Worst case packge the id/name pairs into an xml structure then pass that into the stored proc do do the whole lot at once.

Comment: The second you start wanting to do things in parallel with a DB because its too slow, is the second you need to rationalise that you are probably doing things very inefficiently. Everything you are doing here can be done on the server in one query.

Comment: There is a funny saying, someone is buying oranges for $1 and selling for them $1 and cant work out why he is not making any money... His solution is to buy a bigger truck... or in your case you just want more threads! In short have a look at your issue, and try to work out why its so inefficient, solve the problem first, not just add more threads

Answer (score 0):

As said by TomC and TheGeneral there's probably something wrong with your solution to tackle your problem.
If you want to check how much speed you would gain with simple parallelism you could check out

```
Parallel.Foreach
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd460720(v=vs.100).aspx

But also keep in mind, if you work with multiple threads that you could possibly create duplicates inside the database.
e.g.

```
Thread #1 - enters stored-procedure
Thread #1 - cannot find customer "customerA" -> start transaction for creating a new customer
Thread #2 - enters stored-procedure
Thread #2 - cannot find customer "customerA" -> start transaction
Thread #2 - finish transaction -> return id '42'
Thread #1 - finish transaction -> return id '666'
```

Now you have two customer datasets for the same customer

```
ID  | Name
42  | customerA
666 | customerA
```